# Multiple mvc controller in single page application in mvc using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I have selected **Single page application(MVC,Web api)** in visual studio. Then create two  Asp.net MVC controllers with the name of **HomeController** and **AdminController**.

In Asp.net MVC HomeController, i have 2 partial view first one is **ShowStudents** and second one is  **showTeachers**.
In AdminController, i have 2 partial view first one to **AddStudent** and second one **AddTeachers**.

In **_Layout.html** page i have initialize my angular app `ng-app="myApp"` and in **Index.cshtml** view of HomeController add the `ng-view` directive to display partial view data(of ShowStudents and ShowTeachers).Its woking fine but now the question is how to display partial view(AddStudent and AddTeacher) of AdminController in  Asp.net MVC ?

Comment: Is it possible to call AdminController partial view in HomeController Index.cshtml?

Comment: clearly tell me what are you going to use? angularjs controllers or Asp.net MVC controllers??

Comment: I am using  Asp.net MVC controllers